# Python. Noob. Syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

```
A = int(input()) #recom. sleep time
B = int(input()) #unrecom. sleep time
H = int(input()) #fact. slept
if (A <= H < B ):
    print('Fine')
elif (A < H >= B):
        print('too much')
else (A > H < B):
print('not much')

Error:
 File "<ipython-input-9-12133f4a4c3d>", line 8
    else(A > H < B):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Guys don't be rude, I'm financial and start learning programming :)
I can't see the difference between code who passed errors check and this one.

Comment: `else` doesn't take a test. It's `else:`, always. Use `elif` instead if you need another test. You have indentation issues too.

Comment: thank you! I'm sorry for spamming in your pro-questions place, but i haven't find the answer by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `else` to make a test. You should use `elif`

```
A = int(input()) #recom. sleep time
B = int(input()) #unrecom. sleep time
H = int(input()) #fact. slept
if A <= H < B :
    print('Fine')
elif (A < H >= B):
    print('too much')
elif A > H < B:
    print('not much')
```